# Sample query using public data to test Bi engine Views in Google Datastudio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio, google-bi-engine

Since the update on 20 Feb, BI engine is supposed to support Bigquery Views in Datastudio, I tried using my own data and so far mixed success. For example a left join never worked, only aggregate using the same table seems to work.

If you have BI engine with Bigquery views working for you, can you please provide a sample query using public Data with join?  I want just to test it and see if it works for me.

Update : Support for Join is coming soon, slow roll-out per Region, as per this bug report : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149770979

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have enterprise GCP account and many Datastudio dashboards.
Many of them are using BQ view as a datasource, I don't see BI engine support for BigQuery views as of now. **It says support for views and SQL is limited at this time.**

Here is a screenshot from one of the dashboard with BQ view as a datasource.
[image: Datastudio dashboard with BQ view]

I don't want to disappoint you my friend but as of now this is how it is.